# Django: run a function before accessing the media through url

Tags: python, django, media

I am writing a django project. In my project, there will be pictures that is not stored in the database, but on the media folder. Everyone can just type `http://mywebsite/media/pictures.jpg` to view the pictures. What should I do if I want to run a function first before user access to the media url?
Scenario:

1. User type `http://mywebsite/media/pictures.jpg` and press enter
2. Run a python function in backend, for example simply print out the username
3. Print the username
4. User can finally go to the url to view the picture without knowing there is a function just ran

Comment: Media files are not served by Django in production, so you should configure nginx to do adminstrative tasks before accessing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement a custom solution for this, somewhat like a central view, which will take the URL of the media, do the necessary and redirect the user. Somewhat like this:

#### View

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import Http404

def MediaServeView(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', None)
    if not next: raise Http404("Unknown Media File")

    # Execute custom scripts
    if request.user:
        print(request.user.username)

    return redirect(next, status=302)
```

#### Urlpattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('servemedia/', MediServeView, name="servemedia"),
]
```

#### In your template or URL Resolver

```
<a href="{% url 'servemedia' %}?next={{ yourmedia.url }}" />

u = reverse('servemedia') + "?next=%s" % yourmedia.url
```

Hope it helps.